# pdo mysql insert puts the same thing in multiple fields

Tags: php, pdo

Okay so for some reason this query:

```
$db->sqlquery("INSERT INTO `password_reset` SET `user_email` = ?, `secret_code` = ?, `expires` = ?", array($email, $random_string, $next_week));
```

Enters "random_string" into every field and I have no idea why.

This is my query code:

```
    public function sqlquery($sql, $objects = array())
{
    global $core;
    try
    {
        $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);

        foreach($objects as $k=>$p)
        {
            // +1 is needed as arrays start at 0 where as ? placeholders start at 1 in PDO
            if(is_numeric($p))
            {
                $this->STH->bindParam($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->STH->bindParam($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }


        return $this->STH->execute();

        $this->counter++;
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $core->message($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: What about echoing the values of `$p` in every iteration ?

Comment: I tried that and $p is correct.

Comment: $p are the parameters, it loops through each one if the objects array and $p is the content to put into the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO parameters are bound by reference. So all your parameters are being bound as references to the same `$p` variable, whose value when executing the query is the last element of the array.

Although you said that the value being inserted in all the fields is the *second* element of the array. I'm not sure why that is.

The solution is to use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`.

Comment: Ah i think you may be right, i have yet to test it but i didn't know there where different ways to do it.

Comment: Just tested and you are 100% right, thank you so much, i didn't even think that because it was exactly $p everytime that it wasn't done there and then like bindValue does but stored and then done later like Param does.

Comment: I think another option would be to use `$k=>&$p` in the foreach, so `$p` would be a reference to the array element.